# How to scroll to the end Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm trying to scroll to the end in this page [url](https://www.binance.com/it/pos)

When got into the page, I click the button 'Show all 77 products' I got into a popup that shows partially the elements into the popup. Actually this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

def getpage(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.binance.com/it/pos')
    sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="savings-lending-pos-expend"]').click()
    sleep(2)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-n1ers"]')
    elem.send_keys(Keys.END)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
getpage(driver)
```

I have tried almost everything to work, apart from the solution in the code above, I tried with nu success the current solutions:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

and

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

and in this solutions I didn't understand which label to use

```
label.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

I tried almost all solutions but none worked. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
```

That will make the page scroll down similar to pressing the `Page Down` key.

Comment: I treid it. Compiler gives NO error but it doesn't scroll.

Comment: I forgot to add ```.perform()```. I modified my answer. Try it and let us know

Comment: I found solution. If it works for you up it!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below and confirm:

You can try to find each row and apply `scrollIntoView` for the same.

```
# Imports required for Explicit wait:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def getpage(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.binance.com/it/pos')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"savings-lending-pos-expend"))).click() // show more option
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='modal-wrapper']/div") // Try to find rows.
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",options[i])
            time.sleep(1)
            i+=1
    except IndexError as e:
        print("Exception: {}".format(e.args[-1]))
    print(i)

getpage(driver)
```

Comment: It returns 0 but it doesn't scroll.

Comment: @giacomomaraglino - That's because the `class-name` for the rows was changed. Update the xpath to  `//div[@id='modal-wrapper']/div` and try.

Comment: I found solution. If it works for you up it!

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

def getpage(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.binance.com/it/pos')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"savings-lending-pos-expend"))).click() 
    i = 0
    sleep(5)
    pop_up_window = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='modal-scroller']")))

    while True:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', pop_up_window)
        sleep(1)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
getpage(driver)
```